# C# code not able to open or connect to an encrypted SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I am currently a student in OOP and I have created an inventory management system as my project using SQLite as its database and C# .NET Framework 4.7.2, I am currently using DB Broswer For SQLite to create my database and recently encrypted my database using DB Broswer for SQL Cipher at SQL Cipher 4 defaults and set the password to 123 (just testing on it).

When I connect my encrypted SQLite database using System.Data.SQLite and try to run it,

```
public static SQLiteConnection GetSqlConnection()
        {
            connection = new SQLiteConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\\sqlite\\OOP2_Project.db;Password=123";
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
```

it gives an error on connection.Open(): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.117.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=433d9874d0bb98c5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

So I tried to install Stub.System.SQLite.See to see if it works and it gives me the error on connection.Open(): System.NotSupportedException: '{cannot find a suitable package certificate file for plugin  in "C:\Users\kirby\Downloads\CPE262 Outputs\PRACTICE UI\bin\Debug\SDS-SEE.exml"
: "invalid file name"} {}'. I have noticed that Stub.System.SQLite.See link me up to website to pay for license which is not applicable for me yet.

So I want to ask is there any way to run my program while connected to an encrypted SQLite Database? if so, is there any free license NuGet Package Tool that allows to connect to SQL Cipher 4 defaults encrypted SQLite database?